# How to use native c++ in android code?

Tags: android, eclipse

i have a native class for C++ . but it use in my java class or activity.also give me inform for a hoe to use library of it.

> Blockquote

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to read up on Android NDK.

The Android NDK is a toolset that lets you implement parts of your app using native-code languages such as C and C++. For certain types of apps, this can help you reuse code libraries written in those languages.

For more info, check out this link:
https://developer.android.com/ndk/index.html

Comment: please give an efficient answer. nowadays Kids also know this!

Comment: i'm really not trying to be rude, but if you knew this, then you wouldn't need to ask this question.